# Get the Particular part of the textbox ID in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have the Text box .That text Box ID is **text_1__val**.

I need **1** from that Id.How to Get the Particular part of the textbox ID in jquery which means i need the between _ and __ from that textbox ID?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]`?

Answer (score 2):

If the only requirement is that the character / characters appear between a single and double underscore, try this regular expression match

```
var rx = /_(.+?)__/;
var part = rx.test(idValue) && rx.exec(idValue)[1];
```

This assumes that you're only after the first of any occurrences in your ID value string. If the string fails to match, `part` will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
$(your_textbox).attr("id").split("_")[1]

//Syntax
string.split(separator,limit)
```

Function Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp